# Necessity of Privacy Manifest for third-party SDK in app review

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, wwdc

I am currently working as a app developer, and want to about what's the definition of "third-party SDK" that as mentioned in the WWDC23. From the [Privacy manifest files | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files), We can say that the following targets require a privacy manifest:

> Apps and third-party SDKs — distributed as XCFrameworks, Swift packages, or framework bundles — can contain a privacy manifest file

From my understanding, any external library we used in our app qualifies as a third-party SDK. Consequently, they should all contain a Privacy Manifest.

However, my concern is that in our app. We do use some old libraries that have not been updated for like 2-4 years(e.g.  [ColorAssetCatalog](https://github.com/samrayner/ColorAssetCatalog), [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess)). Under this situations, I would like to know that:

- Does these open-source libraries that does not collect any data that Apple mentioned (including Required Reason API, tracking domain), and only provide source code, require the Privacy Manifest?
- Secondly, would the lack of a privacy manifest in a third-party SDK we used in our app result in failing the app review?

I fully understand that Apple wants to ensure our apps are as transparent as possible, but the details are lacking. Even now, I still can't find a list of "Privacy-Impacting SDKs" or any specific information about them.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could provide further information or insights on this topic. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I faced with the same problem. And after researching their documentation I came to conclusion that for the very old libraries if you aware about what this library does, you can declare needed info in your app's PrivacyInfo...

Comment: @DmitriyMitiai I have the same problem. Are you telling me to add PrivacyInfo to my app if the library developer is not responding??

Comment: @KimJitae Yes. Eventually at the final step everything collects into one file gathering all PrivacyInfos into one. This is the purpose of this PrivacyManifest to simplify the life. So if you know that some outdated library uses coarse location you can mention it in your PrivacyManifest. Because finally this lib will be a part of your code

Comment: @DmitriyMitiai 
There is something I lack a lot of understanding because I use a translator... So if I don't have PrivacyInfo in my third-party library, should I create PrivacyInfo myself in my app project and apply what the library is about? Then, if the third-party library does not have anything corresponding to PrivacyInfo, does it not have to have PrivacyInfo files? Even if there is, can I check the code of the third-party library and put it in my app project PrivacyInfo??

I'm sorry I feel like I'm repeating the same question. English is difficult for me.

Comment: @KimJitae Yes. Create a file and setup it. If your application doesn't directly use some feature, but third-party library does - mention it in your PrivacyInfo file

Comment: Hi @DmitriyMitiai, I am actually a SDK provider. In my SDK, i am not collecting any data. What has to be added in the privacy manifest file of my SDK project. So that I can distribute it to my customers for their smooth app updates in the Appstore. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @GJDK, For more information, please read their documentation. Apple described everything pretty clear. Even if you use UserDefaults, you should mention this. In case you completely doesn't have anything to collect, you can skip it

Comment: @DmitriyMitiai Are you sure that we can skip the need of Privacy Manifest file if the pod does not collect or store anything? I don't see this piece of info in apple doc or WWDC.

Comment: I'm saying not about one pod. I'm just saying that if your application and pods don't use anything described in privacy manifest section, what will add there? I mean if you don't have anything to add there, you can skip it. Of course, if your app uses  UserDefaults, but pod not - you should create privacy manifest. If pod uses UserDefault, but your app not - you should create privacy manifest. On a build step all available privacy manifests in the project(your app and pods) will be merged into one

Answer (score 1):

Apple has included the list here(https://developer.apple.com/support/third-party-SDK-requirements/) of SDKs that require a privacy manifest and signature and you can use Xcode 15 to add **PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy** (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files)and follow the steps in the https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10060/ to get the requirement fulfilled.

Comment: Can I enter multiple reasons in the required description API?

Comment: what about other pods like FSCalendar which is not in Apple Doc's pod list?

Answer (score 1):

Apple requires a Privacy Manifest for any app dependent on the [SDK List defined on their website](https://developer.apple.com/support/third-party-SDK-requirements/). These SDKs should have released (or will be soon releasing) an updated version of their SDK that provides a privacy manifest. A potentially incomplete compilation of statuses is available [here](https://apnspush.com/privacy-manifest-sdks).

In order to use those SDKs in your application and create a privacy manifest, you will need to update your app to the most recent version of the SDK. Recommend pinging the developers on Github for details and status updates.

Comment: What if developer of library does not include privacy manifest till 1st May? Should developer of mobile app (who is using this library), remove the library from app to be able to upload update to AppStore or will be other way to deal with that?

Comment: Which SDK are you talking about? Most should have published by now.

Answer (score 0):

> However, my concern is that in our app. We do use some old libraries
> that have not been updated for like 2-4 years(e.g. ColorAssetCatalog,
> KeychainAccess). Under this situations, I would like to know that:

We are in the same situation, what we have decided is we use this [tool](https://github.com/omarzl/ios_17_required_reason_api_scanner/tree/binary_analyzer) to check if the SDK's we are using are dependent on API that need to provide a reason for use.
If yes

1. Open source: we fork it and include it our selves / try to remove the dependency.
2. Proprietary: connect with the support team. for paid SDK's the teams are professional and are providing with updates.

> Secondly, would the lack of a privacy manifest in a third-party SDK we
> used in our app result in failing the app review?

Yes of course as per here:
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=3d8a9yyh

> Does these open-source libraries that does not collect any data that
> Apple mentioned (including Required Reason API, tracking domain), and
> only provide source code, require the Privacy Manifest?

Nope they are excluded. We are good to go with them without the manifest.