# How to add a Privacy Manifest well to an iOS third-party SDK?

Tags: ios

I'm looking into Privacy Manifest as an Apple policy change.

I have a problem here.. some of the libraries I use are no longer updating. (e.g. GCDWebServer)

I can't find a library to replace it, so I'm going to fork the library, and I'm going to add Privacy Manifest.

[Apple API Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api)

I will download the fork library into my Mac and search the entire API list announced by Apple above through Xcode one by one.

If I find a problem API, I will add it to Privacy Manifest. Is this a good way to do it???

Is there any better way??

Comment: You may want to look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10060/) on wwdc 2023.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Necessity of Privacy Manifest for third-party SDK in app review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77400419/necessity-of-privacy-manifest-for-third-party-sdk-in-app-review)

Comment: @HangarRash No..Even in that question, the answer hasn't run yet. I've looked up about Privacy Manifest, but so far the bottom line is that Apple hasn't answered clearly.