# Do we need to generate Privacy manifest for SDKs or the SDKs will take care of it themselves

Tags: ios, privacy-manifest, required-reason-api

Do we need to generate Privacy manifest for SDKs or the SDKs will take care of it themselves?

As I was going through the documentation I'm unable to understand whether I have to take care of the Privacy manifest or the SDKs maintenance team will take care off it or we both have to work upon it.

While Uploading the app of the App Store it gives the following warnings -

Although submission for App Store review was successful, you may want to correct the following issues in your next submission for App Store review. Once you've corrected the issues, upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

**Missing API declaration -**

```
NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategory SystemBootTime

NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFile Timestamp

NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategory DiskSpace

NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults
```

Comment: Are you using any of those APIs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Necessity of Privacy Manifest for third-party SDK in app review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77400419/necessity-of-privacy-manifest-for-third-party-sdk-in-app-review)

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the info for your app's use of these categories, and if you have any third-party dependencies, they must provide the info for their library.