Is Private Manifest necessary in iOS app?
Is Private Manifest necessary in the iOS app?
If the app doesn't use API from the privacy list.
In the documentation says that the app "can contain a privacy manifest file".
That means that it is not necessary.
I read all the documents and instructions but didn't find explicit information.

Does this answer your question? Necessity of Privacy Manifest for third-party SDK in app review

I think there's no need, because I tried submitting to TestFlight for Apple Review and it passed

This answer is a bit short, you only refer to own experiences. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77400419/necessity-of-privacy-manifest-for-third-party-sdk-in-app-review or here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/743295?answerId=776587022#776587022 or here: https://developer.apple.com/support/third-party-SDK-requirements/

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
